# Heroku-kafka - log4j

Tags: heroku, apache-kafka, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to configure data pipeline from heroku postgres to snowflake using kafka and kafka connect through circleci.

we can populate data from Heroku Postgres to kafka topic properly.
But when we create sinkconnector for kafkaconnect to snowflake via Dockerfile.

we can't achive the target neither we can't see any related logs in Heroku Logs.

So wanted to configure log4j for kafka and kafka connect to see what is happening.

we configured log4j.properites under heroku /etc/kafka folder , but can't able to see the corresponding log file generation.

Below is my log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, stdout, file, kafkaAppender, connectAppender

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.kafkaAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
#log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.File=/etc/kafka/kafka-server.log
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.connectAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.connectAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
#log4j.appender.connectAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/connect.log
log4j.appender.connectAppender.File=/etc/kafka/kafka-connect.log
log4j.appender.connectAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/state-change.log
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stateChangeAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.requestAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
#log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.File=/etc/kafka/kafka-request.log
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.requestAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.cleanerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/log-cleaner.log
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.cleanerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.controllerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/controller.log
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.controllerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

log4j.appender.authorizerAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
#log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=${kafka.logs.dir}/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.File=/etc/kafka/kafka-authorizer.log
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.authorizerAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n

# Change the two lines below to adjust ZK client logging
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO

# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
#log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka=TRACE, file
#log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=TRACE

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
#log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=TRACE, file, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=false

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
#log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=false
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false


log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE, controllerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.controller=false

log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO, cleanerAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.log.LogCleaner=false

log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE, stateChangeAppender
log4j.additivity.state.change.logger=false

# Access denials are logged at INFO level, change to DEBUG to also log allowed accesses
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=INFO, file,authorizerAppender
#log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=false
log4j.additivity.kafka.authorizer.logger=true
```

Comment: You say you're using a dockerfile, but does Heroku mount the /etc/kafka folder from the container to actually read logs? I'd assume it just reads the stdout/stderr from the container. In any case, you never assign the ConnectAppender to a package or log level

Comment: Given my Dockerfile pasted in main thread. Also am new to Heroku, Docker and Log4j, would be helpful if you gave details on how to get this sorted out.

Comment: I don't know how Heroku works. Can you link to documentation how logs are gathered? And you need a line like `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.connect=INFO, connectAppender`